# How other program language clients use Spring Cloud Config Server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

There is a mention in the 'Spring-Cloud-Config-Server' documentation that says,

> To use these features in an application, just build it as a Spring
>   Boot application

Does this mean that my client app also needs to be a Spring Booot application ? Can't i have a Non-Java application accesing the properties in the Config Server via RESTService calls ? If the data is receieved in JSON format, I could always have a JSON parser in my non-java application to parse and use the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard uri's are `/{name}/{profiles}` and `/{name}/{profiles}/{label}`.  These return a json format optimized for the spring cloud config client.

`{name}` is the application name. `{profiles}` is a comma separated list of profiles.  `{label}` is the branch name when using git or svn.

The following return the data in other formats optimized for those formats:

- `/{name}-{profiles}.properties`
- `/{label}/{name}-{profiles}.properties`
- `{name}-{profiles}.json`
- `/{label}/{name}-{profiles}.json`
- `/{name}-{profiles}.yml`
- `/{name}-{profiles}.yaml`
- `/{label}/{name}-{profiles}.yml`
- `/{label}/{name}-{profiles}.yaml`

Comment: I'm sure there is also a way for normal spring (non boot) applications to use the spring cloud config client - but unfortunate this is not documented at all :(

Answer (score 1):

Other language clients can use it like a rest resource. The client can construct the url based on application, environment and key and make a request to cloud config server.

Answer (score -1):

I will still recommend, to have some java library (spring cloud client) in between. Though you can manually parse JSON response but you will have to make sure, you get key/value from first occurrence. Also, you will have to write own logic to replace values from config-server, if overridden by your own cmd line or properties file.