# Spring Cloud Config + ejb

Tags: java, spring, ejb, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am setting for my application set the 'Spring Cloud Config' (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) to make all the centralized settings, however there is a problem, I have a set of 10 applications, however an application is using legacy EJB, there are some connector or customer 'Spring Cloud Client Setup' for EJB?

Answer (score 0):

Non-Spring java apps and non-java apps can use the spring cloud config server rest api.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602935/how-other-program-language-clients-use-spring-cloud-config-server).

You would probably be interested in these endpoints that return the values in java properties format:

```
/{name}-{profiles}.properties
/{label}/{name}-{profiles}.properties
```

See more examples [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.0/spring-cloud.html#_quick_start).

Comment: first thanks for the reply!

My doubt is this, the 'Spring Cloud Config Client' makes a series of settings to facilitate the use of the properties, there is some client already implemented for 'EJB' or 'CDI' to do the same? Something like 'Spring Cloud Config CDI Client'.

Comment: Everything the config client does depends on Spring in general and Spring Boot specifically, there is no specific support for CDI at the moment.

Comment: @spencergibb will you welcome a pullrequest for this project [link] (https://github.com/awwal/spring-cloud-rest-client) that wraps the spring cloud config rest api in java objects.

Answer (score 0):

I was once in your shoes, I created this library [spring cloud rest client](https://github.com/awwal/spring-cloud-rest-client/releases/download/1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.lawal.spring.cloud.rest.client-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar%20/) to do just that. It basically makes use of the rest-api and returns a java properties object which you can use in the EJB or non-springboot environment.

Answer (score 0):

Using the spring-cloud-rest-client almost solves this issue, but one part still remains with regard to nested properties, which the old java.util.Properties doesn't handle. As example the configuration could be like:

```
part: def
sub_alpha: abc${part}ghi
```

The spring cloud config clients resolves the sub_alpha to sub_alpha=abcdefghi, but this way will give sub_alpha=abc${def}ghi.

I'm still working to solve the problem, but I guess someone had the problem before.

Comment: Ok, solved it with using the PropertyPlaceholderHelper, as described the first example of http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper