# spring-cloud-config client without Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am just getting into spring-cloud-config and I'm working on [this basic project](https://github.com/making/config). I would like to know if it is possible and how to rewrite this client to not use Spring Boot.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class ClientApp {
    @Value("${bar:World!}")
    String bar;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String hello() {
        return "Hello " + bar + "!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClientApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that we are thinking of using spring-cloud-config in our spring batch web service, but we use the old spring with xmls, not spring boot. I couldn't find any documentation related to this.

Comment: Currently you would need to use the rest api directly.  See my [answer here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653767/spring-cloud-config-ejb/29654910#29654910

Comment: so a spring boot app cannot be downgraded to old spring?