# Spring Cloud Config Server without Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have looked at [spring-cloud-config client without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693826/spring-cloud-config-client-without-spring-boot) and many others and have not found a convincing answer. So here it goes again:

**Question**:
Is it possible, in a Spring app, to use Spring Cloud Config server/client without the automagic configuration of Spring Boot? Is using Spring Boot a requirement for using these frameworks?

If it is:

1. Is there any documentation that clearly describes what needs to be done in order to enable Spring Cloud Config server/client without Spring Boot?
2. Is there any sample project that clearly describes what needs to be done in order to enable Spring Cloud Config server/client without Spring Boot??

Comment: Yes, you could use it without boot. No docs or examples exist.

Comment: What would be the general recipe for using it without boot? I am happy to figure it out, if you could provide a few hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of documentation or a sample project. However we are doing it in our projects.

You just need to include the configuration server URI as a property source, assuming you are using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" id="propertyPlaceholder">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>http://your-config-server.com:8888/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

You have to make sure to pass -Dspring.profiles.active=current_profile to the java command line, like you probably would have done with boot.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That helps.

Comment: Could someone add a sample application with the source-code? You could specify the URL as follows: `${spring.cloud.config.uri}/${spring.application.name}-${spring.profiles.active}.properties`. That way, you can easily migrate to Spring Cloud at a later time.