# Spring cloud config client without auto configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud

First, please allow me to acknowledge that I am new to Spring and also there are a few questions ([Spring Cloud Config Client Without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367425/spring-cloud-config-client-without-spring-boot) and [spring-cloud-config client without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693826/spring-cloud-config-client-without-spring-boot)) out there on Spring Cloud Config Client without Spring Boot.  However, mine is a, well, a bit different...:)

1. I definitely want to use Spring Config Client without Boot if possible.  I have been trying it over the last couple of days and failed.  If you have any examples, I would like to see.  I can always call Rest API and parse JSON, but would like to use the Cloud Config Client instead.
2. I am, however, not opposed to using Spring Boot.  Although, it would be nice to convert my existing Spring MVC application to Boot ([Traditional Development](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)), how can I just use Cloud Config Client and Actuator (/refresh and other endpoints) dependencies with Boot and exclude other dependencies?  If you have any working example, I would like to see.

> EDIT: A bit more information for #2 since I do not have enough reputation for comments: 
>   @spencergibb, Thank you for answering #1.  For #2, is it possible to exclude all the auto configurations in (/spring.factories) and just bring in config client and actuator dependencies only?  Since @EnableAutoConfiguration has exclude attribute, though verbose, can it be used or are there alternatives?

Would you please guide me with examples, if any?

Comment: Our answers haven't changed for #1 and the two answers you linked to: it's possible, it's not our goal. I don't understand #2 week enough to answer. What parts of boot would you want to exclude?

Comment: Spring Boot is smart enough to detect what you already have configured (datasources, web related parts etc.). So introducing Spring Boot to a legacy application is generally not that hard, the only thing you might need to do is upgrade the Spring version (depending on how old the version is).