# Spring cloud config client without Eureka, Ribbon and spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have spring web application (not spring boot) running in AWS. I am trying to create centralized configuration server. How to refresh the spring-cloud-client after the changing the properties? As per tutorial

> Actuator endpoint by sending an empty HTTP POST to the client’s refresh endpoint, http://localhost:8080/refresh, and then confirm it worked by reviewing the http://localhost:8080/message endpoint.

But my aws Ec2 instances are behind the loadbalancer so i can't invoke the client url. I didn't understand the netflix Eureka and Ribbon much but it seems like adding another level of load balancer in the client side. I don't like this approach. Just to change a property i don't want to make the existing project unnecessarily complex. Is there any other way? or Am I misunderstood Eureka/Ribbon usage?

I have looked at the [spring-cloud-config-client-without-spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367425/spring-cloud-config-client-without-spring-boot), [spring-cloud-config-client-without-auto-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025227/spring-cloud-config-client-without-auto-configuration?rq=1) none of them have answer. First thread was answered in 2015. Wondering is there any update?

Comment: Eureka and ribbon have nothing to do with config client. There is an HTTP api to config server, but it is still something that you would have to implement on the non-boot client.

Comment: @spencergibb could you please explain about Http Api? or provide reference link? How do client refresh the property changes?

Answer (score 1):

To get the configuration properties from a config server. You can do a http request. Example:

From the documentation we can see:

```
/{application}/{profile}[/{label}]
/{application}-{profile}.yml <- example
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.yml
/{application}-{profile}.properties
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.properties
```

So if you would do a request to `http://localhost:8080/applicationName-activeProfile.yml` you would receive the properties in .yml format for the application with that name and active profile. Spring boot config clients would automatically provide these values but you will have to provide em manually.

You don't need Eureka/Ribbon for this to work, it's a separate component. 
More info: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_config

Maybe you could even use spring-cloud-config but I'm not sure what extra configuration is needed without spring-boot. 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/

Comment: @spencergibb  thanks for the explanation. If spring boot refresh the properties automatically what happens to active requests?

Comment: active requests to what?

Comment: @spencergibb if I have 3 instances sitting behind the load balancer and load balancer is the URL that has been exposed, If I call refresh api on client , it will trigger it on one of the three instances. Not all three. What should I do to ensure that I can get every instance refreshed.